# how to send your long WhatsApp message as a single message instead of multiple messages

Tags: python, selenium, whatsapp

I am facing issue while sending a long message to whatsApp Web using selenium Python. My message is in UTF-8 formate. Below is the sample of the message.

સમરાદિત્ય ચરિત્ર
      ભવ – ૧
      ભાગ – ૨૫

પ્રથમ ભવ:-
ગુણસેન(રાજા) – અગ્નિશર્મા (પુરોહિત પુત્ર)

રાજમાર્ગ પરથી મહાજનોના ૧૦૮ રથોને રથમહેલ તરફ જતા જોઇને, નગરવાસી લોકો અનેક તર્ક-વિતર્ક કરવા લાગ્યા.

Also please find the code I have tried so far.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import codecs
import time

#This code is to deal with the input files
grp_list_file = codecs.open('grp_list.txt','r','utf8')
grp_list_data = grp_list_file.read()
grp_list_split = grp_list_data.split('\n')
grp_list_len = len(grp_list_split)
grp_list_val_data = []

for i in range(grp_list_len):
    temp = grp_list_split[i]
    temp1 = temp.replace('\ufeff','')
    temp2 = temp1.replace('\r','')
    grp_list_val_data.append(temp2)
print('Input file processed successfully')


#This block deals with the input message file
msg_list_file = codecs.open('message.txt','r','utf-8')
msg_list_data = msg_list_file.read()
print('Message file input processed successfully')

#Keep this at here to avoid any future issues
grp_list_file.close()
msg_list_file.close()


#Open the whatsapp web
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
input('Enter anyhing once the QR code has been scanned successfully')
act = ActionChains(driver)


#Let proceed with the sending message to all groups
for i in range(grp_list_len):
    name = grp_list_val_data[i]
    message = msg_list_data
    #Select the group
    user = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@title = "{}"]'.format(name))
    user.click()
    msg_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_3u328')
#    msg_box.send_keys(Keys.SHIFT)
    act.send_keys(Keys.SHIFT,message).perform()
#    msg_box.send_keys(message)
#    act.key_up(Keys.SHIFT)
    send = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_3M-N-')
    time.sleep(10)
    send.click()
    print('Message sent successfully to : ',name)
```

Could anyone please help to send the entire text in single message instead of multiple message.

Comment: Or else how to copy variable data to clipboard (or need to copy using ctrl + a and then ctrl + c )in Python and press ctrl + V and paste to WhatsApp message text box

Comment: Can you elaborate on "single message" instead of "multiple messages"? Right now, it seems you're sending the same message to multiple individuals

Comment: Sending single line message to multiple user is working fin. But when it comes to send message with (enter value) it is not working fine. It is sending the message in parts (nearly equal to number of enter). One way is to press shift key and then type the message. But I am not sure how to achieve that. Another option is to copy paste. But not sure how we can copy message from variable to clipboard.

Answer (score -1):

I found the way to solve the issue with help of copy paste idea. 
First I copied my data to clipboard and then pasted it to desired text box location.

Thank you very much for your time and help. :)